# I need an algorithm to invert a triangular matrix

Tags: matlab

I need an algorithm to invert a triangular matrix:
eg

| 1 2 4  |

| 1 3 9  |

| 1 4 16 |
Thanks for your help

Comment: Part of using the `homework` tag is telling us what you've tried.

Comment: How is the matrix you show a triangular matrix? Perhaps you need to re-read that chapter in your text first, before you worry about computations on this matrix.

Comment: I believe what you have is a Vandermonde matrix, which has a known closed-form inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a triangular matrix but this will work

```
Y = inv(X)
```

where X is your original matrix. If you need a specific algorithm you could try Gaussian elimination as a start point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination . You could implement that algorithm and use the `inv` function to check your results.

You could also try Gauss-Jordan elimination http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination

Other more advanced options are these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inversion#Methods_of_matrix_inversion

This should clarify what a triangular matrix is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix